# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'

Tags: python, string

I am a newbie to python and just started to learn the basics. I tried searching for this in many threads, however, I could not find a suitable answer.

I am writing a program to multiple square meters with a pre-defined value and printing the output, this works if the input is >0 or <=0.
It doesn't work when I give the input any word (string), the reason I think is the float definition I did in the input. It doesn't work if I remove the float. I am not sure on how to correct this.

```
sqmt = float ( input ( "please enter square meters:" ) )
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'
```

Comment: Use try catch block for value error.

Comment: Thank you Prajwal, I searched on that and used try except valueerror and it worked.